# $.unique with jQuery, not working for this

Tags: jquery, unique

I'm trying to understand where is my mistake,but can't see it right now, my js is valid and working with other html template :

```
//DATES : wrap the submenu by year
var arr = $("#submenu a").map(function () {
return $(this).attr('year');
}).get();
var results = $.unique(arr);
var i;
```

alert(results);

This works fine but not with the structure I made in this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/moabi/c9nbu/
and I get as a result : year-2013,year-2012,year-2013
not really unique, right ?!
Thank you

Comment: *"Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. **Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.**"* --> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.unique()` only sorts and removes dups from an array of DOM elements per the jQuery documentation, not an array of strings.

If you want to remove dups from an array of strings, you can use this function:

```
function removeDups(arr) {
    var result = [], map = {}, item;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        item = arr[i];
        if (!map[item]) {
            result.push(item);
            map[item] = true;
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```

Here's your jsFiddle modified to use it: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/MBMsz/